# How to setTheme to dark on one Button

Tags: java, android, xml, material-design, toolbar

Guys are possible setTheme from ThemeUtils with one button ?? look at screenshot just one button 'invert' to set Light to Dark and Dark to Light ? if possible how to do it ?? pls help me

my code :

```
case R.id.Invert:
            ThemeUtils.setTheme(this, "dark");
            return true;
```

look this image : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5SpWSpauPDuSGtWREgybnB6aEk/view?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the `setTheme` method on the `Activity` before calling `SetContentView`

Therefore to change theme of an `Activity` that is already open, you would need to restart it.

For example:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTheme(YOUR_THEME_FROM_SHARED_PREFS);
    setContentView(...)
}
```

and

```
case R.id.Invert:
            // Set theme in shared Prefs here

            this.recreate(); // restart the activity
            return true;
```

Comment: i mean on one Button can set Two theme , 1. to set Light to black if current theme is white, and 2. if current theme black the button will setTheme to Light ?? i have create theme on 2 button, i want just in one button, like 'Invert' colors

Comment: No. You have to do it like my answer explains. You cannot change the theme of an Activity that is already open.

Comment: You can use your button to choose the theme (which is why you save it to shared preferences) but you would still need to restart the Activity for it to take effect

Comment: On a specific view, it is not a theme, but a style. A theme is for the entire activity or a larger group of views.

Comment: He is not asking how to change the style of one button. He is asking how to use one button to toggle a theme between dark and light instead of using separate buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure. Define theme, you want to set in `style` folder. And instead of your string write code `R.style.YourOwnTheme`

Comment: i have already make a theme. but i wanna change theme by current theme, 

if (current theme == Light){
setTheme(dark);
}
else if (current theme == dark){
set Theme(light);
}
Like this

Comment: @WahyuHidayat you can get theme by code : this.getTheme().getResourseId() And than check it by this.getTheme().getResourseId() == R.style.YourTheme

Comment: @WahyuHidayat don't forget to restart activity after

Comment: where i put that code ?? this.getTheme().getReourcesId() ?? on MainActivity or on ThemeUtils ? 

   @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
 {
  switch (item.getItemId()){
   case android.R.id.home:
    drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
   case R.id.Invert:
    ThemeUtils.setTheme(this, "Light");
    return true;
  }
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }

Comment: @WahyuHidayat in your if statement

Comment: it showing error

if (item.getTheme().getResources()==R.style.AppThemeDark){
// my theme
}

Comment: the '==' canot be applied to instance of type 'android.content.res.Resources' and 'int'

Comment: @WahyuHidayat try to surround with this code item.getTheme().getResourses() this.getResources().getIdentifier();